# What is this piece of hardware?

Tags: hardware

My wife wants to know. Her sister has a giant bag of them. She thought I would know, but I don’t. [image: item][image: item]

The outside diameter of the finely threaded side is 27mm.

Comment: 1/2" EMT compression, *to-box* connector, with a UL stamp and a plastic insert; suitable for exterior.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are box connectors for EMT conduit which is used to carry electrical wires.

Comment: EMT is Electrical Metallic Tubing, commonly called electrical conduit. The photo is of a fitting that attaches an electrical conduit to a junction box or distribution panel. The coarsely threaded side screws into the box. The band slips over the end of the conduit under the knurled nut, the end of the conduit is inserted into the rest of the fitting, then the nut is tightened over the fitting to compress the band and secure the end of the conduit in place.